# mouseenter + mouseleave / hover on two different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi ive got this piece of code to deal with mouseenter and leave on 2 superposed div

When a user mouseenter the main div the sub div is showed, and if the user get in the subdiv the subdiv must remain, but if the user get out the maindiv and is not in the subdiv the subdiv must be hidden, try with my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rgkcp/

but the timer is not run in my piece of code

```
  $(".bulleHome").each(function () {
      var subDiv = $(this).find(".mupHome");
      $(this).mouseenter(function () {
          $(this).find(".mupHome").css("visibility", "visible");
          $(this).find(".mupHome").animate({
              marginTop: '-23px'
          });
      });
      $(this, subDiv).mouseleave(function () {
        // this is not run
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
              $(this).find(".mupHome").css("visibility", "hidden");
              $(this).find(".mupHome").animate({
                  marginTop: '+23px'
              })
          }, 50);
      });
      $(this, subDiv).mouseenter(function () {
          clearTimeout(timer);
      });
  });
```

And the html :

```
<div class="bulleHome ombreV">
    <a href="http://preprod.mupiz.com/georges-barret" style="font-size:0.7em;text-decoration:none;" pid="13200">
        <img src="http://www.mupiz.com/images/img-membres/images_4958C.jpg" alt="Georges profil" height="100px"><br>
    </a>
    <div class="mupHome" style="visibility: visible; margin-top: -23px;">
        <img src="http://www.mupiz.com/images/mupitR.png" alt="Mup It!" id="bouton-ajout-ami13200" onclick="alert('ok')" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="tMupHome">Mup it!</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the linked css :

```
.mupHome{position:absolute;color:#fff;background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";width:100px;visibility:hidden;height:19px;}
.tMupHome{position:relative;top:-8px;left:5px}
```

Any ideas ?

Js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rgkcp/

Thanks!

Comment: Please show relevant HTML when you post Javascript such as this. How do we know your HTML markup is inconsistent with the scripting otherwise?

Comment: Yep, for this kind of code I suppose the real factor in helping you on this issue is to see the HTML. Throw some lines [here](http://jsbin.com) and in your Question too.

Comment: When leaving one of 2 divs, and not be hovering the other, you want to execute something, is that it? Can you show us some html?

Comment: I added the JsFiddle and the html, thanks

Comment: sorry... may you clarify how it has to work?

Comment: I just updated my main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a var X and set it to false. Then if your mouse go over the SubDiv , you set it to true :

```
$(".mupHome").mouseenter(function () {
      ondiv = true;
  });
```

After this, you just have to verify if the var X is set to true when you leave the first div, if yes, you do nothing. if it still set to false, you hide the SubDiv :

```
$(this, subDiv).mouseleave(function () {
      if(ondiv === false)
      {
          $(".mupHome").animate({
              marginTop: '23px'
          },function() {
              $(".mupHome").css("visibility", "hidden");
          });

      }
});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgkcp/33/).

Comment: This dont work the animation dont go back at the "basic position" visibility:hidden etc.. And if the user just enter in the .bulleHome and not only in the .bulleHome, this will not work

Comment: What do you mean ? And if the user just enter in the .bulleHome and not only in the .bulleHome , can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the div to move back out of the way and disappear when the mouse leaves the sub div. If that is the case this should work fine. If it is not we could definitely use some clarification. You were changing the visibility before the animation, so the animation would not be visible. There were a couple missing quotes in the fiddle as well.

```
    $(".bulleHome").each(function () {
  var subDiv = $(this).find(".mupHome");
  $(this).mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).find(".mupHome").css("visibility", "visible");
      $(this).find(".mupHome").animate({
          marginTop: '-23px'
      });
  });
});
// Added Code 
$('div.mupHome').on({
mouseleave: function() {
$(this).animate({marginTop: '+0px'}, 1000, function(){$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');});}
});
```

Also on the mupHome div the style was not closed out correctly, not sure if this is true in your real code or not

```
<div class="mupHome" style="visibility: visible;>
```

Should be

```
<div class="mupHome" style="visibility: visible;">
```

Comment: Not exactly i want 1) that the div to move back out of the way and disappear when the mouse leaves the sub div. 2) to move back the div when the mouse enters too .bulleHome but not .mupHome

Comment: Changing the marginTop: to 0px will bring it back to where it was. In this case at least as the sub div is superimposed on the parent div the mouse cannot leave the sub div without leaving the parent div. I will clean this code up a little to remove the unnecessary functions